# Protect certificate access with TouchID on iPhone?

Tags: safari, certificate, touch-id, face-id

I installed a personal X.509 certificate on my iPhone (SE, iOS 14.0.1).

I can use it on websites (in Safari) to authenticate myself, but with no permission check at all. Unlike for example filling in saved password into login forms and similar, which requires TouchId each time.

Is there a way to make it ask for permission each time the certificate is used? Similar to the use of saved passwords, so that it would require TouchId or FaceId (or passcode).